# 'str' object is not callable - Converter

Tags: python, string, syntax, converters

As I run my code, the program always returns:

`'str' object is not callable` in the ninth line and I don't know why.

```
sum = 0
count = 0
binNum = input('Input your number: \n')

while count != len(binNum):
  if binNum(count) == 1:
    sum = sum + 2**count
    count = count + 1
  else:
    count = count + 1
if count == len(binNum):
    print(sum)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you expect `binNum(count)` to do?

Comment: Do you want to reproduce [`print(int(input('input binary ("01") number: '), 2))`](http://ideone.com/YTr0gn)?

Comment: If you are on Python 2 then you use `raw_input()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to access the `count`th character of the string `binNum`, and see if it is the character '1'. In which case, you should use square brackets. And compare it to the character '1', not the digit 1.

```
if binNum[count] == '1':
```

By the way, if you're trying to convert a string of ones and zeroes into its equivalent decimal number, you're scanning over the digits backwards. In your algorithm, the leftmost digits contribute the least to the sum, and the rightmost digits contribute the most. You may want to reverse the input string before scanning it.

```
binNum = input('Input your number: \n')
binNum = binNum[::-1]
```

Comment: work`s but i done it differently, where input was changed to `binNum = str(input('Input your number: \n'))` and if statement to `if int(binNum[count]) == 1:`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
if binNum(count) == 1:
```

to

```
if count == 1:
```

Also, you could convert input line as:

```
binNum = str(input('Input your number: \n'))
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve in your code. I was pointing out syntax errors.

Comment: to convert binary number into decimal. but now it Works well with solution given by Kevin